# Search engine for .net

Tags: c#, search-engine

I am looking for a search engine that can be used for sites. Sometimes we dont want to use google embedded search or the complication of lucene.

I run in to these requests:
Crawl based search
Rating and ranking of content based on content types
Searching documents like pdf and docs etc..

I dont mind if it is a commercial control that we have to purchase but I would like to be able to integrate it nicely in to some of these use cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [dtSearch](http://dtsearch.com/) in the past which I know has a web crawler built into it.  It doesn't come with a front end control though, it's strictly a search engine.  You need to write your own results control.  It does have a powerful query language though that lets you score on multiple dimensions depending on how you set up your indexes.  It also has a decent .NET API to work with.

I don't know that this is any less complicated than Lucene though.  So then I start to wonder what complications you are hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be Lucene.net. Recently the status of this project is becoming questionable (not certain of the details). Here is the site: https://lucenenet.apache.org/

Looks like you can still download the code. Probably not much development going forward.

Bob

Comment: the latest version of Lucene.NET seems to be pretty stable though, I just wouldn't take for granted that it will keep up with the Java version at this point. +1 it's a very viable option.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (built using Lucene) - it offers a RESTful interface for integrating into .NET or whatever platform you prefer. It offers all the goodies could ask for without concern for compatibility Java .NET versions etc.

You can easily integrate Solr into your .NET app using [SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)